# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional yet the variable has a value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making a simple to-do list app. I have created a custom `tableviewcell` with a label and a `textview` in it. The label is for the title and the `textview` is for the description. When I try to run the app, it crashes and gives me the following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The error is thrown on the line:

```
cell.taskTitle.text = task.title
```

but the print statement on the line above prints out `"Optional("Task 1")"`.
Why is this?

Here is the whole function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath)
        as! TaskTableViewCell

    let task = taskList[indexPath.row]
    print(task.title)
    cell.taskTitle.text = task.title
    cell.taskDescription.text = task.description

    return cell
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
My taskList is declared globally as:

```
var taskList: [Task] = [
    Task(title: "Task 1", desc: "Task 1 desc"),
    Task(title: "Task 2", desc: "Task 2 desc"),
    Task(title: "Task 3", desc: "Task 3 desc")
]
```

My Task class:

```
class Task {
var title: String?
var description: String?

init(title: String, desc: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.description = desc
}
```

}

Comment: I believe the issue is located in your definition of your task.  Can you show how you declare taskList and how you declare you task objects?

Comment: You can think of an Optional as a Container Object for another Object, If you force unwrap using the ! operator and the Optional is NIL it will result in a Runtime Exception

Comment: You may also want to check your TaskTableViewCell definition, if your IBOutlet have ! replace them with ? or double-check those outlets are properly connected.

Comment: You **must not** declare properties as optional if they are initialized non-optional in an `init` method. Never do that. Remove the question marks. And surprisingly the code does compile and your `Optional("Task 1")` unexpected behavior disappears.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after removing the question marks. However the print statement now prints "Task 1"

Comment: I just wanted to indicate a very bad programming habit, not to answer the question. Are the outlets of the cell connected?

Comment: No worries, Yes, both outlets are connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're looking in the wrong place. What's `nil` is not `task.title`. It is `cell.taskTitle`.

Of course, now you probably want to know why *that* is. It's because you are configuring your cell dequeuing mechanism incorrectly. You didn't show how you are doing that, so we have to guess. A common mistake here is to call

```
tableView.register(TaskTableViewCell.self...
```

That will actually *prevent* your cell from being loaded from the storyboard or xib file, and so all your cell's outlets are `nil`. If you have a line like that in your code, then:

- If the cell is designed in the storyboard, delete that line.
- If your cell is designed in a xib file, then replace that line with:

  ```
  tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"TaskTableViewCell", bundle:nil)...
  ```

Comment: I deleted that line and now it gives me the error:
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Apparently this is something to do with referencing outlets?

Comment: Interesting. The error will usually say a lot more than that, though (in Xcode's Console pane); can you see if it does?

Comment: It also says this at the start:
2018-08-10 21:31:10.010093+0100 Someday[41553:1623841] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier taskCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: I have just changed all of the cell references etc and I no longer get the NSInternalInconsistencyException. Now, however, I am back to square one with the nil found while unwrapping an optional

Comment: Solved it! I had to change
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath)
        as! TaskTableViewCell
to:
let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TaskTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TaskTableViewCell

Comment: What you meeded to do (still need to do) is replace `tableView.register(TaskTableViewCell.self` with `tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"TaskTableViewCell"...`

Answer (score 1):

First of all it would be better if you used some commands like "po" to display the value of each variable to see whether it was created or not secondly I had this problem before the I used willdispaly function which is a property of the table view and it has a great strength it tells hey you the table view cell finished its load and will about to be display is there anything left you want to change in it before displaying it in this way you are sure that everything was built fine and no nils